# Autohotkey: Make Windows 10 text scrubbing closer to OS X

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How can I get text scrubbing (Alt + Left / Right / Up / Down) to work more like a Mac on Windows 10? I have CTRL and ALT switched already via:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt
```

Now I want to make:

Win + Left / Right / Up / Down to perform like (the original) CTRL + Left / Right / Up / Down **(Scrubbing by word)**

ALT + Left / Right / Up / Down to perform like OSX's CMD + Left / Right / Up / Down **(beginning or end of line / file)**

Comment: Does [PureText](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/27880/12318do) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to remap shortcut keys?

```
SendMode Input   ; use SendInput by default for Send

;#IfWinActive, ahk_exe someProg.exe  ; ← #IfWinActive would go here

; Remap Win+ArrowKey to Ctrl+ArrowKey
*#Left::Send ^{Left}
*#Right::Send ^{Right}
*#Up::Send ^{Up}
*#Down::Send ^{Down}
```

If you want to use the Windows key for `CMD` then...

```
; Remap Alt+ArrowKey to Win+ArrowKey
*!Left::Send #{Left}
*!Right::Send #{Right}
*!Up::Send #{Up}
*!Down::Send #{Down}
```

The star modifier `*` allows other modifier keys to be present/active and still trigger.  You may or may not want it.  And you may need to send `{Blind}` (i.e., add this to the send statements) if you don't want the additional modifiers released.  See documentation for [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

If you'd like these swaps to only work in certain programs, use an `#IfWinActive` statement preceding the reassignment statements in the script.  Alternately, `#If WinActive("ahk_exe ProgA.exe") || WinActive("ahk_exe ProgB.exe")` if you want them swapped for multiple (but not all) programs.

It should be evident from above what the key modifiers are (Ctrl = `^`, Alt = `!`, Win = `#`)... the full list is available here: [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Also, should you eventually need to do more than simple one-liners for key reassignments, just put the statements on the line after the hotkey definition and use a `Return` statement to do multiple things for a single hotkey trigger, i.e...

```
; Scrub the clipboard of formatting and paste... 
; This takes two commands, list on the line after hotkey definition
#IfWinActive   ; Reset conditional so this will trigger in any program...
+^v::
    Clipboard := Clipboard  ; Reassign only text back to clipboard vs. ClipboardAll
    Send ^v
Return
```